SymEngine-0.11 was asked to deserialize an object created using SymEngine-0.13.'
I have checked my SymEngine version and it's 0.13 but I'm still getting this message.
I restarted my notebook, uninstall SymEngine and downloaded it again and it still doesn't work.
FYI I am using a MacBook Air m2 and I'm not sure if the apple environment affect the SymEngine library.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
